# Enable server-status on my web server

Tags: apache-httpd

I want to enable server-status in my web server running Linux Mint 17. I don't know where to put `extendedstatus ON` and what else to change.

Comment: What server-status? Any particular program/package that you use/expect?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're asking about how to do this for accesses to your system from a web browser? `http://localhost/sever-status`? If so this is a feature of the web server, typically Apache. So that needs to be installed, it needs to be running and the `server-status` and `extendededstatus` need to be configured in the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. This location might be slightly different on Linux Mint (that's where it is on Fedora) but that file needs to be edited.

The Apache config file, `httpd.conf` is very well documented so if you search for "status" within it, you'll find both statuses and how to enable it. Be sure to restart Apache after you make any edits to that file.

#### Example

```
#
# ExtendedStatus controls whether Apache will generate "full" status
# information (ExtendedStatus On) or just basic information (ExtendedStatus
# Off) when the "server-status" handler is called. The default is Off.
#
ExtendedStatus On

#
# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
# with the URL of http://servername/server-status
# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
#
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

You'll want to make sure that this module is uncommented too:

```
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
```

Comment: I have been running Apache since 1998 (!) and never used this. I actually can access http://localhost/server-status without any changes %-)

Comment: @Anthon - Same here, kind of. I just tunnel via `ssh` to any servers that I want to see status' on rather than open up this config. With an SSH tunnel I can then access any remote ports locally via my web browser. The above config is from a Apache server that I set this up on long ago and just left.